# Android Management API Maximum time for device to sync policy after patch

Tags: android-management-api

Is there a maximum time from when a policy is patched to when a device syncs the newly patched policy? As an example if a device is provisioned and active then powered off, the policy assigned to this device is patched, 45 days later the unit is powered on, will there be any problem applying the policy to the device?

Answer (score 0):

If the device does not check in for 45 days, the user token on the device expires, so it may disappear from the API. The default expiry time for device data is 30 days, if that’s older than 30 days it will be removed from the database.